# How to use HTML5's localstorage with Jquery's select2 plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

Is there a way to use HTML5's localstorage method with Jquery's `select2` plugin? Right now when I enter data and close the browser/tab, all entered data is gone, which is not so optimal since it can get confusing if you dont remember what you've entered

My select2 code looks like this:

```
$(".select").select2({
minimumInputLength: 1,
multiple: true,
query: function(query){

    $.getJSON( 'url path to remote API', {
      name:query.term, 
      featured:true
     }, function(results){

        var data = {results: []};
        $.each(results.data, function(index, item){
            data.results.push({id: item.artist_id, text: item.name});
        });
        query.callback(data);   

     } );
}
});
```

Any help is very appreciated

Comment: you mean you want to re-select items that you've selected? (just want to clarify)

Comment: @bruchowski hmm yeah, I want already entered items to appear and in general, items to stay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this a try: http://jsfiddle.net/7267rkxy/12/

I commented the code for you for some explanation of what's going on, you should be able to just swap out the `data` option with your `query` option and it should still work

PS: I noticed none of your answered questions have been marked 'accepted', if someone gives you an answer that you like or that works for you, you should mark their answer 'accepted' by clicking the checkbox next to the answer

---

HTML

```
<!-- setting a hard width for example -->
<input type="text" class="select" style="width:200px;" value="" />
```

JS

```
// set value property to local storage value
$(".select").val(localStorage.s2options);

$(".select").select2({
minimumInputLength: 1,
multiple: true,
data: [{id: 1, text: 'option1'},{id: 2, text: 'option2'},{id: 3, text: 'option3'}], //sample data
initSelection: function (element, callback) {
    // initSelection only fires when there is something in the value property
    callback($.parseJSON(element.val()));
}
}).on('change', function(info){
   // checking if we have anything stored in local storage
   var s2options = localStorage.s2options ? JSON.parse(localStorage.s2options) : [];

   // add / remove options
   if (info.added) {
       s2options.push(info.added);
   } else if (info.removed) {
       s2options = s2options.filter(function(opt) {
           return opt.id != info.removed.id;
       });
   }

    // save selections to local storage
    localStorage.s2options = JSON.stringify(s2options);
});
```

Comment: When I clear the cache and return to the page, fields are empty. How can I load already entered data into this? I have an remote endpoint, and I want to load the previous entered items into the input fields by using the `.get('path to remote json')`

Comment: `localStorage` isn't permanent, you should be saving to a database if you want to keep them around long term

Comment: Yeah you're right! Actually, I'm posting to a database, so basically, to show already entered items which have been saved into db was the original idea...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @bruchowski 's answer, the newer version of Select2 has a different way of doing this (`initSelection` and `query` are still supported for backwards compatibility though):

You have to create a custom [DataAdapter](https://select2.org/advanced/adapters-and-decorators#dataadapter) and implement `current()` and `query()`.

Comment: DataAdapter is quite a heavy solution (and requires AMD-ification of your code).
The current solution consists to 1. render your html select 2. check localStorage or ajax to update the HTML 3. apply select2